# Select ListItem in ListBox based on Text from TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to select an item in a ListBox based on text entered in a textbox using jquery.  If the length of the text entered in the textbox is greater than 1 I would like to loop through the items in the ListBox and compare the value of each item and if it matches the numbers entered in the textbox I need to select/highlight it in the ListBox.  Here is what I am doing but doesn't seem to work.  The ListBox ListItem's are populated at runtime from the database.

Asp.Net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMediaCode" runat="server" MaxLength="2" Width="40px" />
<asp:ListBox ID="lsMediaCodes" runat="server" Width="296px" />
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#txtMediaCode').keyup(function () {
            if ($('#txtMediaCode').length > 1) {
                $('#lsMediaCodes').each(function (i, option) {

                    if ($(option).val() == $('#txtMediaCode').val()) {
                        $(option).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }

                });
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtMediaCode').keyup(function() {
        console.log('in')
        if ($('#txtMediaCode').val().length > 1) {
            $('#lsMediaCodes > option').each(function(i, option) {
                if ($(option).val() == $('#txtMediaCode').val()) {
                    $(option).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is your code with a couple of changes -

- It now checks the length of the value in '#txtMediaCode' textbox
  rather than how many elements are on the page
- The each selector has changed to `$('#lsMediaCodes > option').each(`
  this will select all option elements rather than just the list itself

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rMW2b/1/

Comment: Thank you to everyone who replied and Thank you to ipr101, it works perfectly.  Sorry I had left off the .val().length on the textbox...typo but your  $('#lsMediaCodes > option').each works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
selectMediaCode ($("#<%txtMediaCode.ClientID%>").val());

selectMediaCode = function(text){    
    $("#<%=lsMediaCodes.ClientID%> option:contains('" + text + "')").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

You could also do it this way too:

```
selectMediaCode = function(text){     
    $("#<%=lsMediaCodes.ClientID%> option[value='" + text + "']").attr("selected", "selected"); 
}
```

**EDIT**

I think you could even do this:

```
selectMediaCode = function(text){     
    $("#<%=lsMediaCodes.ClientID%>").val(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a number of things in order to make this work.  First, you need to use a selector like the following for any ASP.NET control:

```
$('#<%= lsMediaCodes.ClientID %>')
```

When an asp.net control is rendered is has IDs that are very different from what you gave the asp.net control.

Next you will need to look at what html elements the ListBox is generating to hold each list item and select those rather than your ListBox.

When you create an ASP.NET control in your project it does not render as ASP.NET, it renders as HTML.  Because of this you must figure out what each control renders as if you want to work with it using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  We have our client id mode set to static in the web.config so we do not get the .net generated id's.  I am getting the id of the listbox and textbox correctly but the each loop doesn't seem to be working.  Do you have any suggestions on what might be wrong inside the each loop or with the loop itself?

Comment: I believe in your example that `option` in your call back function will be `lsMediaCodes` instead of it's child elements.  I would take a look at how the child elements are being rendered and change your selector to something like: `$('#lsMediaCodes .childElement').each(`